# I'm looking for a pair of SQL functions (MS SQL Server) that will return the MAX or MIN of a list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min, unpivot

I'm looking for a pair of SQL functions that will return the MAX and MIN value of a list of dates (or, alternatively, the MAX and MIN of two dates - I can then stack the calls to handle the whole list). I can't use the MAX() and MIN() functions (as far as I can tell) because that will return the maximum or minimum value of a particular column. What I need is the maximum or minimum column for a particular row.

Here is some sample data to illustrate what I'm looking for:

Current query results:

```
MyID    Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4
---------------------------------------------------------
ROW1    1/1/2019    4/23/2020   12/4/1980   5/2/2020
ROW2    6/3/2020    1/1/2020    5/3/2021    11/9/1998
ROW3    8/15/1980   7/4/2019    12/1/2030   1/2/2020
```

Desired query results:

```
MyID    MaxDate     MinDate
---------------------------------
ROW1    12/4/1980   5/2/2020
ROW2    11/9/1998   5/3/2021    
ROW3    8/15/1980   12/1/2030
```

(Here, I have 4 different date columns. In my actual situation, I will need to sift through 8 different columns.)

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    MyID,
    MIN(Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4),
    MAX(Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4)
FROM ...
```

Or, if necessary, I could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    MyID,
    MIN(Date1, MIN(Date2, MIN(Date3, Date4))),
    MAX(Date1, MAX(Date2, MAX(Date3, Date4)))
FROM ...
```

Obviously, the existing MIN and MAX functions don't work this way. Is there an alternative function that does? I can probably construct some kind of CASE clause that will do this, but it seems like it would be very ugly... It may be a little cleaner to use nested IF statements, though still pretty ugly. I'll start messing with that after I post this. I'm just hoping for a more elegant, cleaner solution.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running. The answer is vendor-dependent.

Comment: @GMB You're correct - I should have included my platform. In this case I'm on MS SQL Server.

Comment: OK, so you have better options than `union all`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard SQL solution is to UNION all your dates

```
SELECT MyID, MAX(thedate ) AS maxdate, MIN(thedate ) AS mindate
FROM
(
SELECT MyID, Date1 AS thedate FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT MyID, Date2 AS thedate FROM table
UNION ALL 
SELECT MyID, Date3 AS thedate FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT MyID, Date4 AS thedate FROM table
) T
GROUP BY MyID
```

There might be better other solutions with window functions, depending on your RDBMS, which you haven't specified. But this one should work with any RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Most, but not all, databases actually support `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select t.*,
       least(date1, date2, date3, date4) as min_date,
       greatest(date1, date2, date3, date4) as max_date
from t;
```

The only caveat is that the return value is `NULL` if *any* of the values are `NULL`.  That doesn't seem to be an issue based on the example data in your question.

EDIT:

On SQL Server, you would unpivot and use `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(dte) as max_date, min(dte) as min_date
      from (values (t.date1), (t.date2), (t.date3), (t.date4)) v(dte)
     ) v
```

Comment: Someone commented that I should have included my database platform in my tags - and of course I should have thought of that. I have done that now.
This is on SQL Server, and "least()" is not an existing function.

Comment: @SeanWorle . . . I just edited the answer.  This is a more efficient solution than the version that uses `group by`.  And yes, you should tag the database.  GMB had already commented when I saw the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here - after a fair amount of digging I don't think there is a good existing solution for this. So I ended up writing my own functions to handle this.

Here is the code for those functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.maxDate(@date1 DATETIME, @date2 DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result DATETIME
    IF @date1 > @date2 SET @result = @date1
    ELSE SET @result = @date2
    RETURN @result
END
go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.minDate(@date1 DATETIME, @date2 DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result DATETIME
    IF @date1 < @date2 SET @result = @date1
    ELSE SET @result = @date2
    RETURN @result
END
go
```

This then allows for a query similar to the second suggestion in my question:

```
SELECT
    MyID,
    dbo.minDate(Date1, dbo.minDate(Date2, dbo.minDate(Date3, Date4))),
    dbo.maxDate(Date1, dbo.maxDate(Date2, dbo.maxDate(Date3, Date4)))
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, where `least()` and `greatest()` are not available, I would recommend a lateral join to unpivot the columns to rows, and then aggregation to pull out the min and max value:

```
select t.myid, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select max(dt) maxdate, min(dt) mindate
    from (values (date1), (date2), (date3)) x(dt)
) x
```

This is more efficient than `union`, because it scans the table only once (as opposed to once per `union` member).